# Python - datetime.time() comparison returns AttributeError as 'str' object

Tags: python, datetime, attributeerror

I'm trying to compare datetime objects in a list to a constant datetime, but I keep getting returned `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'time'`

The list:  `hetero_lst = [datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 8, 6, 45), 'Meeting 1', '45 mins', datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 8, 7, 15), 'Meeting 2', '45 mins', datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 8, 12, 0), 'Meeting 3', '30 mins']`

The following...

```
for element in hetero_lst:
    print(type(element))
```

...returns:

```
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

Here's when I get my AttributeError on line `if t2.time() < t1:`

```
t1 = time(hour=10,minute=0,second=0)

for i in reversed(range(len(hetero_lst))):
    t2 = hetero_lst[i]

    if t2.time() < t1:
        print("Deleted item {}".format(t2))
        del t2
    else:
        pass
```

I really don't get it. Please can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error because you are trying to call an attribute (in this case a method) **.time()** on an item in your list of type **str**, and str-objects does not have any attribute named .time(). To circumvent this you could first check whether the current variable in the list is of type datetime using the method **isinstance(t2, datetime)**, and if so do the other check.

```
from datetime import datetime, time

lst = [datetime(2021, 2, 8, 6, 45), 'Meeting 1', '45 mins', datetime(2021, 2, 8, 7, 15), 'Meeting 2', '45 mins', datetime(2021, 2, 8, 12, 0), 'Meeting 3', '30 mins']

t1 = time(hour=10,minute=0,second=0)

for i in reversed(range(len(lst))):
    t2 = lst[i]
    if isinstance(t2, datetime) and t2.time() < t1:
        print("Deleted item {}".format(t2))
        del t2
    else:
        pass
```

**also**: The code in your loop won't change the list. The only thing the **del t2** does is that it removes the reference to the same memory address as lst[i]. If you would want to actually delete that item in the list, you would have to do it by calling **del lst[i]** instead. Otherwise, if you print the list after your for-loop above, you'll see that no items are removed.

A more efficient way of writing that for-loop would be something like below:

```
for i, possible_datetime_item in enumerate(lst):
    if isinstance(item, possible_datetime_item) and item.time() < t1:
        print("Deleted item {}".format(possible_datetime_item))
        del lst[i]
```

Comment: Excellent, that works! Thanks.

I did play a couple of times with `isinstance(t2, datetime)`, but it is supposed to return a boolean so I don't understand why it circumvented the issue when combined with AND statement. I understand that calling .time() on a str won't work, but when I print(type(element)) it clearly returned `<class 'datetime.datetime'>`, not str. Please, could you explain this for future reference?

Comment: if you start by checking the type by using isinstance, the right hand side of the "and" will not even be attempted in case isinstance(t2, datetime) doesn't return true.

Comment: Thanks for adding the comment on `del` btw. I'm sorry, I still don't understand and I really want to get to the bottom of this, as it can serve me in the future. In this line `if isinstance(t2, datetime) and t2.time() < t1:`, how does `isinstance(t2, datetime)` changes `type(t2)` from being recognised as a string to a datetime.datetime?

Comment: There is no change of type.  It is a feature of boolean expressions in python.  If your first expression `isinstance(...)` evaluates to `False` and is followed by `and`, it doesn't need to evaluate the following expressions, because the result will always be `False`.  This is called "short-circuit" evaluation.  You can look it up.